# Flutter SelectableLinkify supports only TextSpan

Tags: flutter

I'm using `flutter_linkify: ^4.0.2` on my flutter app, and when I'm using `SelectableLinkify` I'm getting the above error:

> SelectableText only supports TextSpan; Other type of InlineSpan is not allowed

Here is a piece of my code:

```
Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            SelectableLinkify(
              onOpen: (link) => print("Clicked ${link.url}!"),
              text: document['content'],
            ),
            Text(
              formatTimestampToString(document['timestamp']),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

When I run only `Linkify` I'm not getting this error.

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Please see this: https://github.com/Cretezy/flutter_linkify/issues/79

Comment: Meanwhile this works for me https://github.com/Cretezy/flutter_linkify/issues/79#issuecomment-793093407 thanks to Yuki.M answer